# Creating a dynamic table (to handle Financial Statements) in Power BI with calculated values from another table based on conditions

Tags: powerbi, finance, datamodel

Update 6:

Yes i updated it so its easier to understand. The account_keys are now NE, CM and so on

[image]

And in the Table DimFinancialStatement you see what the numbers are i need. Some of them from the ACFactTable others need to be calculated according to the text in the struktur column:

[image]

red squared the values to calculate. so yes you're right i did a mess there with the ids :(

```
NE = 2100
CM = 3000
PE = 4300
RE = 4400
EBIT = 9500
EBT = 12900
EAT = 13300
```

---

Update 5:

I try to explain it with 2 new draws of what i want to do or what i think i wanna do :D

[image]

So i have Numbers from the System which are just facts. But for the Financial Statement i need additional calculations. This is just a simplified example. However i want to show some Accounts from the System directly in the Power BI Dashboard which represents a financial statement. Then i also want to add the calculated numbers to the same report in between the other numbers. However if i work with a switch and measures it has to recalculate 360 measures every time a user changes a filter. There is no benefit for the user as all the numbers are static quarterly numbers. Since the Calculations and the Account Number Table have the same structure. I was thinking about putting the Calculation back in the Account Numbers table or make a table to combine those 2 so we have all the facts pre renderd when the data is loading rather than when a user interacts with the report. Something like this:

[image]

---

Update 4:

Changed the File according to Sam Nseirs input about the year_quarter column. Yet u cannot connect it to the CombinedFactTable as it would be a many to many relationship. And if i would connect it to the DimDate Table it would not longer be a Starschema

Update 3:

Here the sample file. i filled with dummy data and removed some parts
[enter link description here](https://file.io/xMf1eJdkD60C)

---

Update 2:

[image]

I have the combined_fact_table from the financial system and the DIM Tables to clarify the row values. On the other hand i'm trying to generate a second table in the same structure as the "combined_fact_table" where i want to calculate all the values i need (arround 30k values). The Idea then was to append the calculated values to the combined_fact_table and in the power BI Matrix visual just load the right account_id. In the Table Calculations the account_id is not really an account id but an id to identify if its a calculation. so from 16400 to 18200 in 100 steps are the ids for clalculations all ids before are some accounts from the finacial software.I think this is a pretty stupid yet straight forward solution to my needs :D 2nd way would be to just have measures for all calculations and then another measure to switch between measure or table values. Most important is the performance

---

Update 3:

I changed the tables so you only have a yearQuarter column with e.g. 20191, 20192, 20201, 20202 and so on.

I know tried to use the code suggested by Sam and changed it slightly but only getting blank results:

```
result = 
  var thisUnitNumber = 'Fct_Calculation'[unit_number]
  var thisYearQuarter = 'Fct_Calculation'[year_quarter]
  var factFilter =
    FILTER(
      'combined_fact_tables',
      [unit_number] = thisUnitNumber &&
      [year_quarter] = thisYearQuarter
    )

  return SWITCH( 'Fct_Calculation'[account_id],
    16400,
      CALCULATE(
        SUM('combined_fact_tables'[absolute_value]),
        'combined_fact_tables'[account_id] = 100,
        factFilter
      ),

    16500,
      CALCULATE(
        SUM('combined_fact_tables'[absolute_value]),
        'combined_fact_tables'[account_id] IN {100, 200},
        factFilter
      ),

    16600,
      (
        var a3 = CALCULATE(
          SUM('combined_fact_tables'[absolute_value]),
          'combined_fact_tables'[account_id] = 300,
          factFilter
        )
        var a2 = CALCULATE(
          SUM('combined_fact_tables'[absolute_value]),
          'combined_fact_tables'[account_id] = 200,
          factFilter
        )
        return DIVIDE(a3, a2)
      )
  )
```

And build a Relationship between the 2 table would lead into a many to many relationship. It still feels like I'm on the wrong path and this is not a Best Practice approach. Is it really Best Practice to have Measures for over 30k cells? :S seems to be strange to calculate this values every time a user change a filter. Furthermore, there is no extra value for the user in always newly calculating it :S

---

I have a fact table containing account balances for all units, accounts, year-quarters, and types (actual, budget, forecast). For example:

[image]

On the other hand, I have a table to structure the financial statement:

[image]

The column "calculation" is intended to illustrate what I want to calculate when certain conditions are met.

The desired result is as follows:

[image]

Primarily, my example serves as a placeholder to understand how I can calculate, for instance, the account investments as a percentage of net revenue or occasionally summing up several accounts because they are related. For instance, to calculate free cash flow (a combination of sums and subtractions).

I am unsure whether this should be done in the raw data itself (in this case, it's an Excel file) or in Power BI, and if the latter, what would be considered best practice. Since financial statements are a common topic, I was surprised that none of the solutions I found or tried worked as expected. Is there any way to have different calculations for different conditions in different rows? Or is this approach inherently flawed? What would be the common approach in this scenario?

I would greatly appreciate your assistance <3

As I was unsure how to formulate my question, please feel free to ask for clarification wherever needed.

Comment: Typically, this is done via Measures and calculated as part of the visual(s). You would use functions like `ALL` to get grand totals and `ALLSELECTED` to get column/row totals etc...

Comment: In one of my first tries i used Measures for ever Row and Column combined with a switch element.. this works but leads to performance issues. everytime i change a filter it loas for 4 seconds. Is it not more usefull to put all the calculated values into a table and then load this table into the visual? Furthermore, i don't need the grand totals nor the column, row totals. its calculations like percentage investments from net revenue or cashflow. so it can be +, -, / calculations :S

Comment: 2nd: How would i use the measures in Table or Matrix? 80% of the values loaded into the report are comingn from the fact table with the account balance. and then for this 20% i need a special rule or a switch? isn't that complicated and using a lot of extra performance? :S

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have:

Table: `FactTable`

| unit_number | year | quarter | account_id | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

And

Table: `Statement`

| unit_number | year | quarter | p&l position |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |

Then you can add the following Calculated Column to your `Statement` table:

```
result = 
  var thisU = [unit_number]
  var thisY = [year]
  var thisQ = [quarter]
  var factFilter =
    FILTER(
      'FactTable',
      [unit_number] = thisU &&
      [year] = thisY &&
      [quarter] = thisQ
    )

  return SWITCH( [p&l position],
    1,
      CALCULATE(
        SUM('FactTable'[value]),
        'FactTable'[account_id] = 1,
        factFilter
      ),

    2,
      CALCULATE(
        SUM('FactTable'[value]),
        'FactTable'[account_id] IN {1, 2},
        factFilter
      ),

    3,
      (
        var a3 = CALCULATE(
          SUM('FactTable'[value]),
          'FactTable'[account_id] = 3,
          factFilter
        )
        var a2 = CALCULATE(
          SUM('FactTable'[value]),
          'FactTable'[account_id] = 2,
          factFilter
        )
        return DIVIDE(a3, a2)
      )
  )
```

---

If you like, you can add a Custom Column to both tables for a relationship join like:

```
ID = COMBINEVALUES("-", [year], [quarter], [unit_number])
```

Then you can simplify the above with:

```
result = 
  SWITCH( [p&l position],
    1,
      CALCULATE( SUM('FactTable'[value]), 'FactTable'[account_id] = 1 ),

    2,
      CALCULATE( SUM('FactTable'[value]), 'FactTable'[account_id] IN {1, 2} ),

    3,
      (
        var a3 = CALCULATE( SUM('FactTable'[value]), 'FactTable'[account_id] = 3 )
        var a2 = CALCULATE( SUM('FactTable'[value]), 'FactTable'[account_id] = 2 )
        return DIVIDE(a3, a2)
      )
  )
```

Comment: Thank you very much for providing such a well detailed solution. I tried to understand and replicat it. However i get balnks for all rows. How does the first code snipet knows from which table to take the [unit_number] from? i also tried to explicitly address it with 'Fct_Calculation'[unit_number] still blank results :S
Despite of that i thouht about the relationship between both. since it would be a many to many realationship i think this is not really a good thing to do in power BI :S

Comment: The `Result` column is expected to be in the `Statement` table. The first three `var`s are the current row values of those columns in the same table. Are there any relationships in or out of your equivalent `Statement` table?

Comment: Let me try to clarify with a ERD and what im trying to do. but in General i have a Table with all values from our finance-tool. Those Values are structured to have following Columns: unit_number, type, year_quarter, account_id, absolute_value and from those values im trying to get my calculations done. i did this with a dax switch in my first shot. but it needs 4seconds on every filter change done by the enduser. this is just not really fun :O And since there is no advantage in having it calulcated everytime a user clicks i would like to calculate it whenever i load the data

Comment: If you can provide a link to sample/MVP PBIX then that would be ideal.

Comment: Let me try to fill my PBI with sample data

Comment: The link to the file is in the updated question at the top. thank you for all the help you already provided :)

Comment: Thanks for the file. A few issues in this file. 1 `year_quarter` in the `Calculation` table is missing the quarter. 2 The are no matching `account_id`s in the combined table. Appreciate this is just a sample but wanted to call these out. I'm re-reading the updates you've added to your question, I'm still struggling on the goal. I suspect a Calculated Table is what you are needing, I just need to get a better idea of what it is.

Comment: Thank you for your input. i updated the File with the correct year quarter format. Yes it's true, that there are no matching account_id s in the 2 tables. The Positions in the Calculate Table are calculated from the CombinedFactTable. so it is not the same id but rather e.g. id 1 + id 2 from the combinedFactTable is id 5 in the Calculate table. The sololy goal i have is to combine values from a table with calculated values based on this table and show it in a power bi table visual. It should represent the P&L and some other KPIs you have in financial reports

Comment: Looking at your updated sample file, you don't have any acccount Ids for 100, 200 or 300, hence it is returning blank.

Comment: Thank you for all the time you're invested allready. Very much appreciated :) And sorry for the late reply, i was kind of busy at work :O I did an Update 5 in which i try to clarify what I'm trying to achieve

Comment: Update 5 helps to understand it better. The sample file you provided doesn't have any matching IDs (that you've used in the measure) so it will return blank. Or are you saying we need to append the ID 1 with ID 2 to get the ID in the combinedFactTable (eg "123 & "456", get ID 123456)?

Comment: No, actually there is no ID match at all. i just used the id to have something to reference in the financial statement. so i can just load a table and the id and then get the values for those ids in the table. but the accounts together build a new value which has its own id bcs its a completly new value. i don't know how to explain this any better :( for example we have the account reveneue and we have the account personel expenses. now we calculate percentage for personel expenses of revenue. this is a number we dont have in the fact table so this would be a new fact and therefore new id

Comment: I think you misunderstand me - in your sample file - your `result` calculated column has "if 'Calculation'[account_id] = 16600 then DIVDE( 'CombinedFactTable'[account_id] = 300, 'CombinedFactTable'[account_id] = 200)" but in your 'CombinedFactTable' there isn't IDs 300 or 200.

Comment: you're right i did a messup with the ids. i tried to simplyfi it by naming the accounts NE, EBIT and so on. but behind that i have ids. i wrote you down which one bleongs to wich and what the actual calculations are